# Which twig file is being used and how?

Tags: templating, routes, craft2

I have a page in Craft (2.x) that displays several links and I was able to find which twig file had those links by searching the code base of twigs.  Those links point to some Angular code with links like this:

```
/support/give?source=
```

By trial and error, I discovered that the Angular code is invoked as part of a twig file in craft/templates/_views/  The original conundrum was there were two "give" files:  give.twig and give-new.twig and I didn't know which one was the actual twig invoked.  By trail and error again, I determined it was using the give-new.twig by changing the template.  But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how THAT twig is being invoked.  I scanned for "give-new" in the code, both craft and Angular and I searched in Settings, Routes and Web Content for any reference to it but I cannot figure out how a URL like /support/give maps to the give-new.twig file.

So the question is: How do I know which twig is invoked by a URL?  I am pretty sure that there isn't any Angular code doing this, the Angular code bundle references are in the twig file, but how that twig is invoked is a mystery.  Where do I start in finding the reference?

Comment: Check the `config/routes.php` file, see if it shows up in there.

Comment: I checked the routes.php file and it has no entries except return array();

Comment: Should have checked Routes in settings....I would have found it there.

Comment: Ah... you said "I searched in Settings, Routes", so I thought you had already checked that.

Comment: Wow!  True...so I am not sure why I didn't see it.  Sorry.  Should have walked through what I said I did a second time before I posted.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this variable to get the template name: `{{ _self.getTemplateName() }}`

Put it at the top of all your template files:

`<!-- {{ _self.getTemplateName() }} -->`

And then for every template called it should have the commented out template name.

In Craft 3, there's a nice plugin called "Template Comments" which is great for this... But I don't see a version for Craft 2.

Comment: Thanks.  I know what the template name is, it's give-new.twig.  The issue is, I can't tell HOW and WHERE that particular twig is invoked.  IOW, why is give-new.twig invoked and not the give.twig invoked even though both are in the same folder. Or, said another way, if I decided to create give-brand-new.twig how would I get that twig to display?

Comment: Hmm. I see, i was thinking it'd give context, like looking in the code so see what it's wrapped in. like if you're reading down the compiled page source, you'd see ... <!-- parent file --> ... <!-- give-new file --> ... <!-- other embedded file --> etc. And then you'd be able to see what's wrapped around it, so you'd ave a better idea where to look.

Comment: Uh, additional thought. If it's not in your template code, maybe it's in your database - like there's a global or an entry field that that has "give-new" as text in it.

Comment: OK...I see what you are saying in your earlier comment.  Not sure if help but I may try it.   Just to see what would happen, I just deleted the twig to see what would show up in the logs.  This is what I see:

`2019/08/26 19:25:06 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.404] Craft\HttpException in craft\app\controllers\TemplatesController.php:72

Stack trace:

#0 [internal function]: Craft\TemplatesController->actionRender('_views/give-new', Array)

#1 craft\app\framework\web\actions\CAction.php(109): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(Craft\TemplatesController), Array)`

Comment: OK...I finally found it.  In Routes!  I had been looking in "Reroute" but it didn't occur to me that there would be another routing method.  Thanks for all the help..you gave me a couple of new techniques I can use

Answer (score 1):

The solution was in "Routes" in Settings. I had been looking in "Reroute" but seem to pass over the "Routes" entry...maybe because the names were similar.  In Route there was and entry for support/give --> _views/give-new  and that was the solution.